# Standard user password

Tags: 12.04, password, users

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I was wondering when a standard user is asked for his password, other than on login or lock screen, I am thinking about disabling it completely.

Comment: you want `sudo` not to ask password when you use it?

Comment: Which authentication are you talking about? @theharshest: The standard user is not present in sudoers, so I believe that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: No, standart user (not administrator) can't use sudo, AFAIK and I certainly don't want this user to use sudo commands.
And I guess I didn't use the authenticate word right, should have been just "asked for password".

Answer (score 0):

A user is never asked for its password other then on the loginscreen or the lockscreen.
A user with the correct privileges also gets asked for its credentials when root privileges are required for a certain job. (like update or sudo for a custom command).

Credentials are shared in some circumstances to a proxyserver, mailserver or another 'service'. Be sure they allow for a disabled or empty password.

It might be advisable to disable certain things with users like this:
example:  No "Remember password" in web-browsers; this could be retrieved by anyone with the necessary skillset.